# How to specify the PostgreSQL DateStyle property with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

PostgreSQL supports specifying Date Formats using the DateStyle Property as mentioned here,
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE. (link was originally to 8.3 version of docs).

I could not find any SQLAlchemy ORM documentation reference on to how to define this property. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLAlchemy makes use of the DBAPI, usually psycopg2, to marshal date values to and from [python datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects - you can then format/parse any way you want using standard python techniques.  So no database-side date formatting features are needed.

If you do want to set this variable, you can just execute PG's SET statement:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("SET DateStyle='somestring'")
# work with conn
```

to make this global to all connections:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET DateStyle='somestring'")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. In the meantime as mentioned by you i had used the python datetime formatting operations which are working fine for now.